# 'Select All That Apply' input type on iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-input

I need to add a new question type to a survey app on the iPhone.  I know apple doesn't have an out of the box solution for 'select (or check) all that apply' but does anyone have a creative way to handle this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of implementing such a UI would be a grouped `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` accessoryStyle for the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UITableView, UITableViewCell and UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark. You will be able to implement a table with an multiple rows where it will be possible to select multiple items. It is a common way how to handle such type of UI tasks in iOS. As an alternative you can make UISwitch as an accessory for each of the cells but it is overloading UI and provide bad UX.